# unfortunately, (app name) has stopped working

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, android-emulator

this is logcat:

```
09-05 11:58:12.719: E/AndroidRuntime(710): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
09-05 11:58:12.719: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at com.example.new_idea.second_layout.onCreate(second_layout.java:30)
09-05 11:58:12.719: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5008)
09-05 11:58:12.719: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1079)
09-05 11:58:12.719: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2023)
09-05 11:58:12.719: E/AndroidRuntime(710):  ... 11 more
09-05 11:58:15.560: I/Process(710): Sending signal. PID: 710 SIG: 9
```

second layout.java:

```
package com.example.new_idea;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class second_layout extends Activity {

TextView display_temp;
Button but_temp;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    display_temp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display_temp_id);
    but_temp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_temp_id);
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.ui);

    try
    {
        Thread.sleep(5000);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    but_temp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            display_temp.setText("yes , thread is working");
        }
    }); 

}}
```

so what can i do to solve this problem
I am trying to do program that changes the text view by pressing button "click"
but the emulator gives me error and can't excute the above code

Comment: Only logcat may not help. What's second_layout.java:30? Show relevant code.

Comment: Don't write in comment. Please edit question with code :)

Comment: too long to be pasted here
what can i show it in comment

Comment: i will edit the post it self

Comment: buttons and textview only can be findviewbyid after setcontentview

Comment: Dhruti , Did you know where is the bug ??

Comment: Dhwanik Gandhi , it worked well, thanks

Comment: you are giving the delay of 5 seconds , if you press button immediately it will crash or might be go for Not responding..

Comment: YOUR WELCOME  .. IF MY ANSWER HELPED YOU ,KINDLY ACCEPT AND MARK AS A TRUE ..

Answer (score 0):

```
display_temp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display_temp_id);
but_temp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_temp_id);
```

Move these after `setContentView()`. Before that all you can get is a null, and invoking a method like `setOnClickListener()` on a null object causes the NPE.

Also, remove the `Thread.sleep()`. Never sleep in the main thread.

Answer (score 0):

just change your onCreate method AND remove Thread.sleep()

```
@Override    
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {  
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.ui);

display_temp = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.display_temp_id);
but_temp = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button_temp_id);

try
{
    Thread.sleep(5000);
}
catch (Exception e)
{
    e.printStackTrace();
}

but_temp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        display_temp.setText("yes , thread is working");
    }
});}
```